# how to compare sales current week vs same week last months Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table "sales"

| date | revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06-01(Week 1) | 100 |
| 2022-06-08(week 2) | 200 |
| 2022-05-01(week 1) | 800 |
| 2022-05-08(week 2) | 900 |

and I want to compare sales current week vs the same week last month and get the following result:

| date | revenue June | revenue May |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-01(Week 1) | 100 | 800 |
| 2022-06-08(week 2) | 200 | 900 |

Comment: I think you really need some form of an object to represent a calendar -- like accounting month / week / year for each calendar day.  For example 6/1 was a Wednesday and 5/1 was a Sunday -- how you've correlated them above is a bit subjective IMO.  Any solution you come up with would likely not scale well without this reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
select rn  as week_number
      ,[5] as revenue_may
      ,[6] as revenue_june
from  (
       select revenue
             ,row_number() over(partition by month(dte) order by dte) as rn
             ,month(dte) as mnth
      from t
      )tmp
pivot
(max(revenue) for mnth in([5], [6])) pvt
```

| week_number | revenue_may | revenue_june |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 800 | 100 |
| 2 | 900 | 200 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WeQjlfBl?hide=4)

Answer (score 0):

Based on given data, following is for `postgresql` -

```
with data as (
    select date1,substring(date1 , 1,10) as date_col,
    substring(date1 , '[[:alpha:]]+[[:digit:]]+') as week_col,
    revenue
    from revenue_tab
)
select 
    d1.date1, 
    d1.revenue as june_rev,
    d2.revenue as june_rev
from
    (select * from data 
     where extract(month from to_date(date_col,'yyyy-mm-dd'))=6) d1
join
    (select * from data 
     where extract(month from to_date(date_col,'yyyy-mm-dd'))=5) d2
ON d1.week_col = d2.week_col
AND extract(year from to_date(d1.date_col,'yyyy-mm-dd')) 
    = extract(year from to_date(d2.date_col,'yyyy-mm-dd'))
 ;
```

DB fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vWq1SyrWBvAchzekZHdUG9/0).